# Generating a matrix of possible angles

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, intervals

I need to generate a matrix [1xn] of all possible angles (theta in radians) which belong to 3 intervals: [0, pi/6], [pi/4, pi/2] and [pi, -3*pi/4]. For a moment I have an idea for how to generate 3 different matrices using

```
theta1 = 0:0.1:pi/6;
theta2 = pi/4:0.1:pi/2;
theta3 = pi:0.1:(-3*pi/2);
```

and then join them... are there any other more optimal solutions?

Comment: that looks pretty optimal to me. What do you think you are wasting?

Comment: Note that the last assignment will produce an emtpy matrix...unless you set the stepsize to -0.1.

Answer (score 1):

It's this simple: `[theta1 theta2 theta3]`

If you want to do it in one line only, you can of course do

```
[0:0.1:pi/6 pi/4:0.1:pi/2 -pi:-0.1:(-3*pi/2)]
```

If your question was how to make this in a more "elegant" way, I don't think there is any, because your intervals don't have constant lengths.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the third range of angles above, by adding a minus sign before the left argument. In other words, I changed `pi:-0.1:(-3*pi/2)` into `-pi:-0.1:(-3*pi/2)`. I suppose this is what you meant.

Comment: yes yes, but I can't vote, sorry. It says I don't have enough points of reputation.